# How to package ASP.NET vNext projects and run elsewhere?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I know that in an ASP.NET vNext project directory (where project.json exists), we can execute `k run` (or `k web` depending on the configuration/code) and KRuntime runs/starts the application/server.

I also realized that `kpm build` creates a *.nupkg from your ASP.NET vNext project. That seemed like a sort of packaging to me and I can ship using that. However I couldn't find the correct way to bundle an app with all its dependencies and make it runnable with one command. Is there a way to do this?

My use case will be building a Docker image that has Mono and will just drop the built ASP.NET vNext application in it and provide the entrypoint for the web server with one-liner command, like `k web`. I looked at a few examples but I couldn't find a way to bundle an app with all its dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

KPM pack is what you want. It will create a "deployment image" and a batch script (we don't support .sh yet but will eventually). There's likely a few bugs you will run into on mono:

1. https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/272
2. https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/327

Comment: Is there any documentation on this? The samples on the ASPNET/Home Github repo don't work -- `dnu pack` generates a NuGet package and the /app/ folder with a batch file in it, but running the batch file just spits out errors. `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command
'ConsoleApp'. Available commands: ConsoleApp.
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundExcepti
on(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, Exception innerException)`